# Intellij - Run scala main file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have installed Scala plugin and sbt executer in IntelliJ.
I have created a new Scala project and it created a build.sbt file.
In the project setting/Libraries I see a reference to the SBT I have on my computer.
I created a new Scala class with the following code:

```
class RunMe {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello from main of class")
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find a new type of run configuration to create for the scala class.
I don't see the green play button in the left column (IntelliJ Left Gutter)
What am I missing?

How can I configure a run configuration in the code?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The signature of the class should be `object RunMe`, with `main` method. Or `object RunMe extends App`: in this case the `main` method is not necessary.

Comment: main problem of the example is that class should be instantiated, object not! so the easiest way is to do object RunMe extends App {}. Everything inside {} will be executed in App main func.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `class` with a `static` method, which is what you do in Java, you should use `object` in Scala:

```
object RunMe {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello from main of class")
  }
}
```

You can also mixin a trait called `App` instead of providing the `main` method:

```
object RunMe extends App {
  println("Hello from main of class")
}
```

In both cases IntelliJ should pick the definition fine and offer you the green arrow to start the app.

Answer (score 2):

I usually just mixin the [App](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/App.html) trait into my `Runner` object.  Something like...

```
object RunMe extends App {
 println("Hello from main of class")
}
```

should do the trick.  Intellij should now pickup that this object is "runnable" and provide a "play" button as expected.